# Weird Noise From My Headset's Mic

Tags: microphone, usb-headset

Hello SuperUser Community

i Have a problem in The Recorded Audio Which is a weird Noise in The Background 
it only happens when i Plug in The Charger For My Laptop 
otherwise The Audio Has no weird noise

this is an example of the problem 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05bdK3LYrVJZWhreTNFQTYtUjA/view?usp=sharing

My Laptop Is Lenovo G510

My HeadSet
[http://www.amazon.com/Ertch-Headset-Headphones-Microphone-Station/dp/B01EUUSKT8/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1463507723&sr=8-9&keywords=bass+hd+gaming+headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EUUSKT8)

Comment: Have you tried another headset?  
Or using a just microphone (instead of the headset) for recording?
Also, have you tried plugging the USB headset into the USB port on the other side of the laptop (i.e. the side away from the where the charger plugs in)?

Answer (score 1):

> it only happens when i Plug in The Charger For My Laptop

this is the problem, interference from the laptop power supply or power section of the motherboard.

1. Move the laptop charger farther away from the laptop using an extension cord, see if this stops the noise.
2. Try a different headset
3. Try a new power supply for your laptop
4. If none of this helps then it is an internal problem with the laptop, possibly a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)) to me. [Here](http://www.epanorama.net/documents/groundloop/) is a good description of it. I would try a different charger and see if the issue remains, but I would NOT try ungrounding your devices.